# Are libfoo.a and foo.lib compatabile formats?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, gcc, compiler-construction, linker

Some build scripts (such as the one in numpy) simply does the following to make a gcc-compiled library archive work with the Visual Studio linker:

```
copy libfoo.a foo.lib
```

Surprisingly it seems to work. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on several factors, it may or may not work - and for a couple reasons. I take it you mean full-on, reversible compatibility.

1. #### For implibs that are used to bind DLLs to executables, the answer is *no*.

   I once tried to link an MSVC++ implib with a gcc-produced dll. If the formats *were* compatible, it would have worked when I renamed the library libfoo.a. 

   To get around this, there is a utility called reimp that can  produce a suitable gcc implib from a DLL. To reverse the process, microsoft's `lib` tool can create a static implib from a .def file, which gcc can produce with a DLL should it be given the correct flags. [Search "reimp" at the mingw website for more info]
2. #### C++-compiled object files are also incompatible because of [Name Mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B).

   Different C++ compilers mangle variable and object names differently, resulting  in "[object] code ... that is not usually linkable"
3. #### For a static library compiled as plain old C? *Yes*

   I'd need a bit more information as to what type of project you are concerned with, but if it is C and the `copy libfoo.a foo.lib` hack worked, this may be the case. Try to see if this works in reverse with Mingw or Dev-C++. **Edit**: Actually, this will only work when the library is compiled with gcc on a Windows platform (and it works both ways!). the only exceptions to this AFAIK are cross-compiled libraries - MSVC refuses to take them, at least with Ubuntu-provided "i586-mingw32msvc-ar".

<s>Another alternative explanation is that MSVC linker is compatible with the .a format for historical reasons. IIRC, it has been around since the days of UNIX. Again, though I could only see this working for pure C, and not C++.</s> 
**EDIT**: It is actually the other way around. The Windows version of the GCC toolkit creates static libraries that are compatible with Microsoft's COFF format.

Comment: Actually the MinGW linker (or more correctly, the binutils port) is written to be compatible with MSVC COFF object file format, not the other way around. For plain C object files it should work for most cases.

Comment: The libraries in question are from lapack - http://www.netlib.org/lapack/ - (libblas.a, libatlas.a, etc..)

Comment: @Filip That explains everything. I was just testing it out, and the MingW build tools on Windows are 100% compatible with MSVC. 

I should point out that this is not the case for libfoo.a when it is cross-compiled for a Windows target. In this case, the format is somehow incompatible with the MS COFF format.

Comment: Don't forget the issue of runtime compatibility.  e.g., if you malloc() some memory with the Visual C++ CRT, and pass it to a LIB or DLL produced by GCC, and that LIB/DLL tries to free() said memory, Bad Things will happen.  Same if you fopen() with VC's CRT, and fread() with GCC's.

Answer (score 1):

While I do not know any details for the lib format, I can give some information on the lib*.a format. This is just a archive of *.o object files, and can be manipulated with the ar program (part of [binutils](http://sourceware.org/binutils/)).

```
prompt>ar t /usr/lib64/libc.a | head
init-first.o
libc-start.o
sysdep.o
version.o
check_fds.o
libc-tls.o
elf-init.o
dso_handle.o
errno.o
errno-loc.o
prompt>ar t /usr/lib64/libc.a | wc
   1447    1447   16904
prompt>
```

I assume then that *.lib also is an archive of object files with either a identical or compatible content index.

Comment: Yes - library files are basically an archive of the object files. The actual question is of course if they are compatible in both-ways (windows msvc <-> unix gcc)